# How do I clear the text in Android TextView?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

So I have an Android program like so:

```
package com.example.androiddemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AndroidDemo extends Activity {
    String[] messages = {"Short Text",
                         "I want to show some really long text" +
                         "on the display of the phone. " +
                         "Having run out of ideas on what to type, " +
                         "I am adding this text which makes absolutely " +
                         "no sense."};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        final Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clrBtn);
        final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v == add){
                    text.setText(messages[new java.util.Random().nextInt(messages.length)]);
                }else if(v == clear){
                    text.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The button to add text to the `TextView` works perfectly fine however the text never clears.
My belief was that the operation of `TextView` would be analogous to `JTextField` or `JTextArea` where setting the text to `""` clears it.

**How do I clear the text?**

Comment: Try not to mix up `TextView` and `EditText`. An `EditText` is analogous to `JTextField`/`JTextArea`, and `TextView` with `JLabel` (and the equivalent larger not-user-editable box)

Comment: @ataulm Thanks for mentioning that !! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class AndroidDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button add, clear;
EditText text;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clrBtn);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v == add){
        text.setText(messages[new java.util.Random().nextInt(messages.length)]);
    }else if(v == clear){
        text.setText("");
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: hmm.. is it a good practice to make an `Activity` a listener or should I make a class of my own and make it a listener ? :-)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, I use this method in my apps. 
Instead of setting the text to `("")`, it clears the stored value using the `getText().clear();` method. Personally, I use this because it looks more professional and makes proper use of the clear command in android.

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText.getText().clear();
                }
            });
```

EDIT: The original post had the tag 'EditText', so I answered the question with that in mind. 
This works with EditText, With a TextView, just call `textview.setText("");`

Comment: Don't see the clear function as you describe it here.

Comment: It works great for me. Are you sure it's an edit text?

Comment: My bad. It's a TextView. Thanks @Avi

Comment: So it only works with edit text. Do you mind removing the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. Your problem is related to the onClickListener.

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v == add){
                    text.setText(messages[new java.util.Random().nextInt(messages.length)]);
                }else if(v == clear){
                    text.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

in this case `if(v == clear)` is always false. You have to register a  `View.OnClickListener()`  for the `clear` view/button, or make your Activity implements `View.OnClickListener` and set  for both the button `this` as `setOnClickListener`

Comment: Can there be a generalized listener which handles all the 2 buttons ?

Comment: yes I already point out in my answer. You can make a class  that implements the View.OnClickLister and use the same instance for both buttons

Answer (score 2):

You're going wrong with your onClick method. You are adding it for 1 button, and then checking which button it is. It is never going to be your 'clear' button, since it only listens to your 'add' button onclick.

Comment: Is it possible to have a general listener which can handle all the buttons by using `if-elseif ladder` ??

Comment: @LittleChild yes, your Activity could be this general listener (see No_Rulz's answer) But you still need to add it to each button.

Comment: Yes, check out No_Rulz his answer. You make your Activity extend OnClickListener (be careful not to import the Dialog one, but the View one!) which will give you 1 general onClick method. You can subscribe all your buttons with something such as button.setOnClickListener(this) then. In the onClick method, just switch/case.

Comment: Sure. so I can define an `onClick(View v)` in the `Actiity` and add it to all buttons. Then it can handle both of them ? :)

Comment: Or add `android:onClick` to your button xml

Answer (score 1):

Use

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button btnclear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

 btnclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tv.setText("");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: not bad, but you should try to provide some information as well